# Overriding GetDirectoryTree.php - preference not working

Tags: magento2, overrides, gallery

Having issues overriding Magento\MediaGalleryUi\Model\Directories\GetDirectoryTree.php.

It is related to a current Media Gallery bug that causes Folders not to display (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30596)

Here is my setup:

di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\MediaGalleryUi\Model\Directories\GetDirectoryTree"
type="Vendor\General\Plugin\MediaGalleryUi\GetDirectoryTree"/>
```

GetDirectoryTree.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\General\Plugin\MediaGalleryUi;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Glob;
use Magento\MediaGalleryApi\Api\IsPathExcludedInterface;

/**
 * Build media gallery folder tree structure
 */
class GetDirectoryTree
{
    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $filesystem;

    /**
     * @var IsPathExcludedInterface
     */
    private $isPathExcluded;

    /**
     * @var Glob
     */
    private $glob;

    /**
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Glob $glob
     * @param IsPathExcludedInterface $isPathExcluded
     */
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        Glob $glob,
        IsPathExcludedInterface $isPathExcluded
    ) {
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->glob = $glob;
        $this->isPathExcluded = $isPathExcluded;
    }

    /**
     * Return directory folder structure in array
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws ValidatorException
     */
    public function execute(): array
    {
        return $this->getDirectories();
    }

    /**
     * Read media directories recursively and build directory tree array in the jstree format
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return array
     * @throws ValidatorException
     */
    private function getDirectories(string $path = ''): array
    {
        $directories = [];

        $absolutePath = $this->getMediaDirectory()->getAbsolutePath($path);
        foreach ($this->glob->glob(rtrim($absolutePath, '/') . '/*', Glob::GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $childPath) {
            $relativePath = $this->getMediaDirectory()->getRelativePath($childPath);
            if (!$this->isPathExcluded->execute($relativePath)) {
                $directories[] = $this->getTreeNode($relativePath);
            }
        }

        return $directories;
    }

    /**
     * Format tree node based on path (relative to media directory)
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return array
     * @throws ValidatorException
     */
    private function getTreeNode(string $path): array
    {
        $pathArray = explode('/', $path);
        return [
            'data' => count($pathArray) > 0 ? end($pathArray) : $path,
            'attr' => [
                'id' => $path
            ],
            'metadata' => [
                'path' => $path
            ],
            'path_array' => $pathArray,
            'children' => $this->getDirectories($path)
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve media directory with read access
     *
     * @return ReadInterface
     */
    private function getMediaDirectory(): ReadInterface
    {
        return $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    }
}
```

module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_General" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>            
            <module name="Magento_MediaGalleryUi"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Any ideas?

I have tried the plugin method too and it also did not work. I think I'm missing something that's preventing me from pulling this class up.

UPDATE:

I looked into debug.log and saw this:

```
main.ERROR: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\MediaGalleryUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Directories\GetTree\Interceptor, Argument 3 passed to Magento\MediaGalleryUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Directories\GetTree\Interceptor::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\MediaGalleryUi\Model\Directories\GetDirectoryTree, instance of Vendor\General\Plugin\MediaGalleryUi\GetDirectoryTree given, called in /var/www/php/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121 [] []
```

I did go through the code generation steps and did remove generation folders:

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf var/generation/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Does module is register and enable into the system?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes, I have put this within an older plugin that is already registered, should I put it into a new plugin completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it done. It required also adding a preference for GetTree.php file.

Here is the whole plugin:

src\app\code\Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Directories\GetTree.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Directories;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\Model\Directories\GetDirectoryTree;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Returns all available directories
 */
class GetTree extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    private const HTTP_OK = 200;
    private const HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR = 500;

    /**
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    public const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Cms::media_gallery';

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var GetDirectoryTree
     */
    private $getDirectoryTree;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param GetDirectoryTree $getDirectoryTree
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        GetDirectoryTree $getDirectoryTree
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->getDirectoryTree = $getDirectoryTree;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $responseContent = [
                $this->getDirectoryTree->execute()
            ];
            $responseCode = self::HTTP_OK;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->logger->critical($exception);
            $responseCode = self::HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR;
            $responseContent = [
                'success' => false,
                'message' => __('Retrieving directories list failed.'),
            ];
        }

        /** @var Json $resultJson */
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setHttpResponseCode($responseCode);
        $resultJson->setData($responseContent);

        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

src\app\code\Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\etc\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\MediaGalleryUi\Model\Directories\GetDirectoryTree" type="Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\Model\Directories\GetDirectoryTree"/>
    <preference for="Magento\MediaGalleryUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Directories\GetTree" type="Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Directories\GetTree"/>
</config>
```

src\app\code\Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">  
    <module name="Vendor_OverrideMediaGalleryUi">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_MediaGalleryUi"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

src\app\code\Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\Model\Directories\GetDirectoryTree.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\Model\Directories;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Glob;
use Magento\MediaGalleryApi\Api\IsPathExcludedInterface;

/**
 * Build media gallery folder tree structure
 */
class GetDirectoryTree
{
    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $filesystem;

    /**
     * @var IsPathExcludedInterface
     */
    private $isPathExcluded;

    /**
     * @var Glob
     */
    private $glob;

    /**
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Glob $glob
     * @param IsPathExcludedInterface $isPathExcluded
     */
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        Glob $glob,
        IsPathExcludedInterface $isPathExcluded
    ) {
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->glob = $glob;
        $this->isPathExcluded = $isPathExcluded;
    }

    /**
     * Return directory folder structure in array
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws ValidatorException
     */
    public function execute(): array
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("==============DIRECTORIES===============");

        return $this->getDirectories();
    }

    /**
     * Read media directories recursively and build directory tree array in the jstree format
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return array
     * @throws ValidatorException
     */
    private function getDirectories(string $path = ''): array
    {
        $directories = [];

        $absolutePath = $this->getMediaDirectory()->getAbsolutePath($path);
        foreach ($this->glob->glob(rtrim($absolutePath, '/') . '/*', Glob::GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $childPath) {
            $relativePath = $this->getMediaDirectory()->getRelativePath($childPath);
            if (!$this->isPathExcluded->execute($relativePath)) {
                $directories[] = $this->getTreeNode($relativePath);
            }
        }

        return $directories;
    }

    /**
     * Format tree node based on path (relative to media directory)
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return array
     * @throws ValidatorException
     */
    private function getTreeNode(string $path): array
    {
        $pathArray = explode('/', $path);
        return [
            'data' => count($pathArray) > 0 ? end($pathArray) : $path,
            'attr' => [
                'id' => $path
            ],
            'metadata' => [
                'path' => $path
            ],
            'path_array' => $pathArray,
            'children' => $this->getDirectories($path)
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve media directory with read access
     *
     * @return ReadInterface
     */
    private function getMediaDirectory(): ReadInterface
    {
        return $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    }
}
```

src\app\code\Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\composer.json

```
{
    "name": "vendor/module-overridemediagalleryui",
    "description": "Overrides Broken MediaGalleryUi",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": "GPL-3.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Vendor",
            "email": "vendor@vendor.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

src\app\code\Vendor\OverrideMediaGalleryUi\registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_OverrideMediaGalleryUi', __DIR__);
```

This is quick and dirty way of doing it, I will probably rewrite it using a Plugin later as it will be an easier implementation.